# I have to sort a stack in ascending order from top to bottom using only one queue

Tags: python, queue, stack

```
def stack_push(stack, a, size):
    if isfull(stack, size):
        print("Error, stack is full")
        return stack
    else:
        stack.append(a)
        return stack


def stack_pop(stack, size):
    if isempty(stack):
        return
    else:
        return stack.pop(0)


def isfull(stack, size):
    return len(stack)>=size

def isempty(stack):
    return len(stack)==0

s1=[20,20,17,99,8,88,3,10]
temp=[]
s1size=8
```

I have to write the rest of the code but I have 0 clue how to proceed from here, what can I do to solve this without using insert or any queue functions? also how do I compare stacks or values from int to queue index values?

Comment: Although a stack can also be called a last-in-first-out-queue (LIFO-queue) you should normally only use "queue" for the FIFO-queue to avoid confusion. Or do you mean that "temp" should be used like a FIFO-queue?

Comment: @MichaelButscher Yeah, "using only one queue" but "without using [...] any queue functions" sounds really weird (even with your possible explanation).

Comment: The question only gave me the stack value, I added the temp myself as the queue to store values and sort but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I think you're right I have to use a temporary stack but with like a FIFO-queue

Comment: @SunjarIbnMasud I guess with "temporary stack" you mean "temp"? If you want to use it like a queue you shouldn't call it "stack". The actual Python name of the data structure used for "s1" and "temp" is "list". A list can be **used as** stack or (less efficiently) as a queue. You should think again about the question and then try to use the right names for the things.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fun one. Even though it might not be what you are asking, there is *a way* to sort a (LIFO) stack using only a (FIFO) queue! Essentially, you just keep the queue in a sorted order, and perform a modified insertion for each element as you go through the stack. Here is some pseudo-code that would carry out the operation:

```
while (!stk.empty()):
    x = stk.pop() # item to insert
    first = q.peek() # first item in sorted queue

    if (q.peek() < x):
        # condition for new largest item
        q.push(x)
        # x will be new first in sorted queue
        first = x

    else:
        # condition for not-largest item
        q.push(q.pop())
        while (q.peek() > x && q.peek() != first):
            q.push(q.pop())
        q.push(x)

    # now loop so queue is back in it's sorted order
    while (q.peek() != first):
        q.push(q.pop())
```

It's not pretty! But it should get the job done.

Comment: how do you do a q.peek before pushing anything to the queue?